# In Google Apps Script, specifically for Sheets, what is the difference between the UnhideColumn and showColumns methods?

Tags: google-apps-script

Both of these methods will show a hidden column. But why have two methods for the same thing? Do they function differently?

Comment: There's also `SpreadsheetApp.getActive() and SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`. I think the only difference is spelling.

Answer (score 0):

They do the same thing but require slightly different parameters.

The method `unhideColumn()` requires a range to unhide if hidden. [App Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#unhidecolumncolumn)

Example: - This will unhide column A

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // This unhides the first column if it was previously hidden
 var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
 sheet.unhideColumn(range);
```

This will unhide columns A & B

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // This unhides the first column if it was previously hidden
 var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B1");
 sheet.unhideColumn(range);
```

The method `showColumns()` requires the column index (A = 1, B = 2 etc) [App Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showcolumnscolumnindex)

Example: - shows column A

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 // Unhides the first column
 sheet.showColumns(1);
```

To show more than 1 column you can use the `showColumns()` method or use a loop with the above code to show what ever columns you need.